# Logistic regression with categorical data

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, interpretation

I'm trying to apply logistic regression to the data with binary predictor. But some of my variables are numerical and some are categorical. If I just do this in R I get the model where for every categorical variable I have coefficients and p-values for for variable's possible values except for the first.

How can I interpret such model?
And what is the best way of finding best model for such problem?

Answer (score 5):

Your coefficients (which are log odds-ratios) are for a particular level of each variable stated relative to a **reference category**. So there is only one coefficient for a two-level predictor, as the coefficient represents the difference in the log-odds between two groups.

That is, if you are interested in modelling likelihood of having a disease (outcome) based on gender (Male/Female) and smoking status (smoker/non-smoker), then the coefficient for gender is the log odds ratio for e.g. Males relative to Females; and the coefficient for smoking is for smokers relative to non-smokers.

For factor variables, R chooses reference groups by default as the first level of that category, which does depend on the order of the levels. (When importing factors, R does this alphabetically, which is why female and non-smoker are the reference categories above. But sometimes the levels may have been applied in a different way, so it's important to check.) See `relevel` if you want to see how change reference categories.

Comment: But how can I use these results then? I mean, for numeric variables I can use these coefficients to construct rule for classification.I have a number of both categorical and numerical variables. And I need to find variables and rule which provide best AUC as well as to calculate their odds ratios.  And also I can use p-values for variables. But here for categorical variable with, for example, 4 possible values I have 3 p-values..

Comment: @Oleg -- these are some quite big questions, and you may need to track down a textbook for details, or pose these as a new question. I'll give a few directions to some of the pertinent points for this particular question in the following comment(s).

Comment: (1) Coefficients from this model are the log odds ratios (which is what the model fits) -- you can exponentiate them to get the odds ratios.   (2) To get a hypothesis test for whether a multi-level factor (eg a four level factor with three coefficients) is associated with an outcome (at all -- a test that all of whether all of the beta coefficients might be zero in the population) one can use Type 3 tests (Wald or likelihood ratio tests would be one option for considering the impact of a set of coefficients.)

Comment: BTW, I think the question parts "How can I interprete such model?" and  "And what is the best way of finding best model for such problem?" are pretty comprehensive, so I can't really attempt an answer.